# How do we get current run instance's configuration name when a gui quicktest executed via hp alm

Tags: hp-uft, hp-alm

I have practically dead exhausted trying to scratch and scrub way to run gui quicktest test configuration from alm with different parameters. For all what I know, uft alm integration does not offer a fairly easy solution.

The only other option is to code the same, however via ota am not able to find the test  configuration name when it is executed from alm. It just gives out the parent test name but not the configuration name.

Any help or direction ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an very easy way to get the run/test name:

**Get the Run Name:**

```vb
Dim CurrentRun 
Set CurrentRun = QCUtil.CurrentRun 
Reporter.ReportEvent 2,"Current Run", CurrentRun.Name
```

**Get the Test Name:**

```vb
Dim strTestname 
strTestname = QCUtil.CurrentTest.Name
```

Keep in mind that both properties wont be accessible when running uft without alm integration.

There is an official [documentation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.53/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#OV_Supp_Util/Utility_QCUtil.htm#Run%3FTocPath%3DObject%2520Model%2520Reference%2520for%2520GUI%2520Testing%7CUtility%2520Objects%7CQCUtil%2520Object%7C_____1) of all vbscript objects that can be used in UFT gui.

*getting the test name using an API Test case is harder, I can post my solution if required*

Comment: Thank you, however the

'''
CurrentRun.Name
'''
does not gives the *name of the configuration* running. 

the correct solution is QCUtil.CurrentTestSetTest.Name (<< This gives the name of the Configuration running) and QCUtil.CurrentTestSetTest.TestName gives the name of the parent test case to which the configuration is associated. 

Am sorry, I was not clear with my question. Perhaps wrong choices of words.

Comment: @IrateINWIT I'm glad I could lead you to the right direction :)